# Rounded edge in Form

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

please tell me how to make shapes with rounded edges (Winforms.) Found this code, but it has problems. when you drag a shape, it is bad draws. And some controls inside have problems with painting too.

```
  [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn(int nLeftRect,
                                                   int nTopRect,
                                                   int nRightRect,
                                                   int nBottomRect,
                                                   int nWidthEllipse,
                                                   int nHeightEllipse);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowRgn(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn, bool bRedraw);

    /// <summary>
    /// radius
    /// </summary>
    public int Radius = 0;

    public AfyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        min_max_closeEvents();
        borderEvents();

    }
```

min_max_closeEvents();
            borderEvents(); - methods for border painting

Comment: That has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18901565/643085)

Comment: @HighCore that question is about something else, and the answer is completely off.

Comment: @Emanuele right on the spot.

Comment: @HansPassant I absolutely like your idea, but you would have to actually draw the whole region - and change it whenever the form is resized. This is harder than just calling a Windows API method with a parameter. However, if you provide code for that as an answer, I'll be sure to upvote it.

Comment: Hans seems to have deleted his comment. He suggested on using the [Region property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) to draw a mask for the form so that the corners would be rounded. More complex than calling the Windows API, but more elegant and maintainable IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want something `special in GUI`, just try **moving to** `WPF`, you would surely love it. For simple application without requiring much customization in GUI, you may use `winforms` but anyway moving to `WPF` is something we should do soon or later. Here is the code I've done before recently. The idea is simple. First we create a `Region` of `rounded rectangle shape`, then assign this region to the `Region` property of the form. However to `Draw` the border, if you create the similar `GraphicsPath` and draw or even fill it, the `border` won't look good because there is some little `gap` between the outermost edge and the `GraphicsPath`.

Here is the [demo's link](http://www.mediafire.com/?4jig88nn65767wm)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, its good solution, but i need to resize form, i need toolbar with caption.By using this method, i havent got borders with ability to resize.(

Comment: @Udjen it's a pain to customize the full featured rounded form like as you want. You should go for `WPF`. Customizing `winforms` today is something just for fun. If we have time and want to find something funny with `winforms customizing`, we will possibly spend hours digging into it.